# Clearing all data and authentication information from Excel Power Query Connections

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I am developing a spreadhsheet that will query the [Azure AD Graph API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api) that I want to make freely available. Naturally, when I develop it I will use my Azure AD users, and query my tenants data. However, I don't want anyone to be able to see my data. I want them to have to provide their own tenant id, and login information and connect on their own.

Is it possible to do the following easily:

- Clear all authentication information from the spreadsheet.
- Clear all results from the spreadsheet

Comment: If I'm not wrong,, you are trying something like Audit Sheet. Yes it's possible to clear all kind of information from the Sheet, even the Data or as you said results even. But I'm unable to realize the purpose!! If you don't like every one to use data then you can set PW method or Login. But All need Programing method. ☺

Comment: @RajeshS The data in the table is loaded through PowerQuery by an OData feed. Depending on who you login as the data is different.